# SQL Multiple counts with 3 tables

Tags: mysql, join, count

I'm building a program (COBOL) using SQL to track the logged time for a special time of users.

I have 3 tables:

```
table 1 - user logged time
table 2 - user logged time
table 3 - user profile
```

The same user is not on table 1 and table 2, and all the users are in table 3.

I have to do a count of how many users with the profile X the last time they logged on where logged for:
less than an hour
between 1 hour and 5 hours
more than 5 hours.

I found a way to do 1 count using table 1 and 3 qith the query:

```
`SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT A.user)                                                           
 FROM table1 A                         
LEFT JOIN table3 B                        
   ON B.user = A.user                             
WHERE B.profile = 'X'                                                      
  AND A.HTIMEST = (SELECT MAX(HTIMEST)                    
                     FROM table1 A     
                    WHERE B.user = A.user)                     
  AND A.time BETWEEN 0 AND 1  `
```

Bt that would mean a lot of querys in just one program.

If you could be of any help I would be very thankful.

Thank you.

```
Table1:
       User  TimeLog     Timestamp
        1      0,5       2019-01-01
        1       6        2018-11-31
        4       2        2018-12-31

 Table2:
       User  TimeLog     Timestamp
        2      0,5       2019-01-01
        3       6        2018-11-31
        5       2        2018-12-31

 Table3:
       User  Profile    
        1        X     
        2        X      
        3        Z
        4        X      
        5        Z
```

Expected result:

```
Time loged   Count
<1h            2 (User 1 e User 2)
>1h -<5h       1 (User 4) (User 5 doesn't have the right profile)
>5h            0 (User 3 doesn't have the right profile, and user 1 has more 
                   recent data)
```

Comment: update your question add  the tables schema, a proper data sample   and th expected  result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [UNION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html) to combine multiple select statements into a single result.

In your case it probably makes sense to create a [VIEW](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/views.html) combining tables `table1` and `table2`.

```
CREATE VIEW logs AS
    SELECT user, timelog, timestamp FROM table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT user, timelog, timestamp FROM table2;
```

Then build query based on that view, `INNER JOIN` ([JOIN reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html)) the users with profile "X", `INNER JOIN` a query that gets the highest timestamp for each user, and use a [CASE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) statement (basically if/else) to determine the time category. Group based on the case statement and count the users.

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN l.timelog < 1 THEN '<1h'
        WHEN l.timelog <= 5 THEN '>=1h - <=5h'
        ELSE '>5h'
    END AS time_logged,
    COUNT(l.user)
FROM
    logs l
    INNER JOIN table3 u ON
        l.user = u.user
        AND u.profile = 'X'
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            user,
            MAX(timestamp) AS timestamp
        FROM
            logs
        GROUP BY
            user
        ) m ON
            l.user = m.user
            AND l.timestamp = m.timestamp
GROUP BY
    CASE
        WHEN l.timelog < 1 THEN '<1h'
        WHEN l.timelog <= 5 THEN '>=1h - <=5h'
        ELSE '>5h'
    END;
```

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rosfAWSoiamyQ49fQkmsTa/0)

Comment: Thank you so much!